# passing argument 4 of qsort from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, strcmp, qsort

please help with this warning:

passing argument 4 of qsort from incompatible pointer type;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BSIZE 200
int (*cmp)(void *, void *);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  FILE *in;
  char buf[BSIZE];
  int i, nofl;
  char *p[20];



  if(argc<2){
    printf("too few parameters...\n");
    return 1;
}
  in=fopen(argv[1], "r+b");
  if(in == NULL){
    printf("can't open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

  while(fgets(buf,BSIZE+1,in)){
    p[i]=malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
    strcpy(p[i],buf);

    i++;
}

  nofl=i;

  qsort(p,nofl,sizeof(int), &cmp);

  for(i=0;i<nofl;i++)
    printf("%s\n",p[i]);

  return 0;
}

int (*cmp)(void *a, void *b){
  int n1 = atoi(*a);
  int n2 = atoi(*b);
  if (n1<n2)
    return -1;
  else if (n1 == n2)
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
}
```

i think this c program must convert string to int and sort by asc. the problem is that with qsort strngs massive takes no effect, it stays the same as unsorted.

Comment: that's not how function pointers work. declare and define `cmp` as `int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)` and then pass `&cmp` (or simply `cmp`) to `qsort()`. Didn't check the code further...

Comment: `int (*cmp)(void *, void *);` says that `cmp` is a function pointer, not a function.

Comment: Change `qsort(p,nofl,sizeof(int), &cmp);` --> `qsort(p,nofl,sizeof(int), cmp);` and also change `int (*cmp)(void *a, void *b)` --> `int cmp(void *a, void *b)`

Comment: `void *a, void *b){ int n1 = atoi(*a);` will not work as `*a` is de-referencing a `void *`.

Comment: @WeatherVane explicitly taking the address of a function isn't an error, just not necessary...

Comment: Note: In `int cmp(void *a, void *b)`, the function will receive _addresses_ of `char *`.

Comment: `while(fgets(buf,BSIZE+1,in)){` --> `while(fgets(buf,  sizeof buf,in))`  `BSIZE+1` is 1 too many.

Answer (score 2):

```
int (*cmp)(void *a, void *b){ ... }
```

is not legal code to define a function.

Instead of

```
int (*cmp)(void *, void *);
```

use

```
int cmp(const void*, const void*);
```

**Update, in response to comment by OP**

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){

  // Here, a is really a pointer to a `char*`.

  const char* pa = *(const char**)a;
  const char* pb = *(const char**)b;

  int n1 = atoi(pa);
  int n2 = atoi(pb);

  // Simplify the return value.
  return ((n1 > n2) - (n1 < n2));

  /***
  if (n1<n2)
    return -1;
  else if (n1 == n2)
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
  ***/

}
```

Comment: thank u , now i have no warnings. i have changed function definition as you sad.<pre><code>int (*cmp)(void *a, void *b){
  int n1 = atoi(*a);
  int n2 = atoi(*b);
  if (n1<n2)
    return -1;
  else if (n1 == n2)
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
} </pre></code>  qsort is not working nothing s changed when im printing strng[i]  massive the elements is still unsorted

Comment: @wakajawaka, did you notice any improvments?

Comment: it gives me no warning. sort doesnt work. it gives me the same result. nothings changed

Comment: OP's original compare `if (n1<n2) return -1;....` does not have an overflow problem like `return ( n1 - n2);`  Idiomatic alternative: `(n1>n2) - (n1<n2)`

Comment: int n1 = atoi(*(char **)a);
int n2 = atoi(*(char **)b);